# CPU fan makes strong noise when opening directories, small programs (like web browser) and when taking the computer out of sleep mode

Tags: cpu, sleep, fan, window, noise

I have a desktop PC with the CPU Intel I7-12700F, the CPU fan Zalman CNPS10X extreme, and Windows 11.

In general the CPU fan is quiet and I don't hear it, but in these occasions I do hear strong noise:

- I open folders in Windows
- I open or close small programs in Windows (like Calculator, Notepad or a web browsers such as Chrome and Edge)
- I am taking the computer out of sleep mode

Why is this happening and how to prevent it?

Comment: "Why is this happening and how to prevent it?" - It likely means the fan is starting to fail.  However, "strong noise" isn't the greatest description of a sound, since you should expect to hear the fan in a system with a Intel I7-12700F to some degree.

Comment: `small programs in Windows (like a web browser` if the web browser is Chrome, that's a bad example. Chrome is a resource hog :p

Comment: What cooler are you using? Stock intel? It's a piece of junk in majority of cases. Any mid-tier after market CPU cooler will do the job far better and quieter

Comment: The cooling is a 6 months old Zalman CNPS10X extreme.

Comment: @Ramhound why is that? I even though of installing a passive cooling for this CPU, such as Zalman FX100.

Comment: 12th Generation Core processors run hot. Hardware typically either fail years down the line or fairly quickly.

Comment: @Ramhound I was sure that computers in 2022-2023 would be freeze cool. I guess I am too optimistic. Perhaps only in 2037...

Comment: What do you mean by “Freeze cool”?

Comment: that chip can consume up to 180W. if you are drawing that much power for any extended period, a noisy fan would be the least of your problems, as you are pushing the limits of conventional air cooling (at least in a home environment where room temp is expected to be human-comfortable). There are chips that you can get and keep close to room temp out there, but yours ain't one of them (and they would not perform the way you obviously want, since you were willing to buy a 350USD CPU).

Comment: @Ramhound I just thought that technology was so advanced that processors created around year 2022 would be very cool, not very hot compared to processors made say in 1990, 2000, 2010 and alike. I might even have a false premise here.

Comment: @FrankThomas I am not sure I fully understand what you wrote (due to my limited knowledge in the subject). You might want to post an answer with further elaboration to clarify for a CPU layman like myself and others what have I done "wrong" or "problematic" to find myself in the situation in which I am right now. Am I too "apettative" for strong CPUs? Are you saying that I bought "too strong of a CPU for homey usage"? Well, I just want speed When loading programs and video game levels...

Comment: @jordanola - Processors have only gotten more complicated, and they also draw more power, more power results in higher temperatures

Comment: If I buy a CPU of say not 350$ but of 1000$ should it make any difference? I know it may seem a naive question but I just try to ask a practical question.

Comment: ok, so in consumer CPUs (we'll leave server chips out of it for now), $350 is the price point for hobbiests/powerusers/gamers, so people who want a very capable system and are willing to spend for it. Just a notch or so down from the top tier. You bought a beast of a CPU, so you need a beast of a cooling system. It won't be quiet when its really working. There is SOOOO much that goes into really understanding system cooling so i don't blame you for being confused, but one of the first things I look at when shopping for a CPU is the TDP/Power Draw. It tells you how easy/hard it is to cool.

Comment: Personally, I've tested my rig, and it can run Prime95 for unlimited periods of time staying under the CPU max temp, and when I stop the program, the CPU temps resume normal (40-50C) inside 20 seconds, so I know my cooling system is sufficient to anything I can throw at my 95W CPU, but boy does it make some noise under a load. full-sized ATX Case case with 7 120mm case fans, and CPU cooler is a big noctua that looks a lot like your zahlman in general design. I recommend you live with the noise, and test your cooling. it may be that water cooling is best for you.

Comment: @FrankThomas primarily for the sake of knowledge, instead of living with the noise, does upgrading the CPU to these 1000$ CPUs and perhaps also the PSU (from 850W to say 1500W) and maybe also upgrading some RAM should reduce CPU heating or fan turbo?

Comment: No, not really. your system isn't struggling, its running full bore like its supposed to. the issue with power isn't that your PSU isn't strong enough, but that all the heat processors generate comes from the power they draw. additional ram would not have any impact. I believe that water cooling is quieter overall, so that may be worth trying if it really bugs you. also be sure to install the chipset drivers and any control software that may have come with your motherboard. some will have options for controlling fan PWM based on sensors if you want to adjust its reactions, if your mobo has it.

Comment: @FrankThomas may I reinforce what you wrote by saying that today I have switched to another CPU cooling with two fans (Cooler Master Hyper 212 LED Turbo ARGB) and I still hear about the same noise... I will live with that noise in this computer.